# Maximize the sum of GCDs (Greatest Common Divisors) of a bipartition?

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

Given an array of positive numbers. I want to split the array into 2 different subset(s) such that the sum of their gcd (greatest common divisor) is maximum.

Example array: `{6,7,6,7}`.

Answer: The two required subsets are: `{6,6}` and `{7,7}`; their respective gcd(s) are 6 and 7, their `sum = 6+7=13`; which is the maximum gcd summation possible.

Gcd: Gcd of `{8,12}` is `{4}` as 4 is the greatest number which divides 8 as well as 12.

Note: `gcd(X)=X` in case the subset contains only one element.

My approach: By brute-forcing, I find all possible sub-sequences of the array,then, I find the maximum sum, but this does not work if the input size is greater than 30 numbers. I am in search of a more efficient approach.

Extra(s): Maximum size of any input number is 10^9 , time limit:-1s seems good, size of input might be as huge as 10^5

Comment: How big can your input be? (30 items can be done easily with brute force, but 3000 items cannot)

Comment: There can be as many as 10^4 numbers in our array.

Comment: What is the maximum size of a number ? Is there a time limit ?

Comment: Maximum size of number is 10^9 , time limit:-1s seems good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is actually an easy problem posing as a difficult one.

First, let's ignore the possibility of values appearing more than once. Obviously, it is best to put all copies of a value in the same set, since moving some of them elsewhere can only hurt the GCD (**edit:** unless there is only a single distinct value). So we'll assume all elements are distinct. Also, let M be the maximum value of any of the elements.

Think about this way: There's a trivial solution of taking the highest element on one side, and all the rest on the other. "All the rest" - may have a GCD of 1 (could be higher of course), so this solution gives you M+1.

Any subset of your inputs with more than a single distinct element cannot have a GCD higher than M/2 (since such a divisor has to be multiplied by another divisor, which is at least 2, to get to the original value, which is no higher than M). So **edit:** an optimal solution cannot be made up of two sets with multiple distinct element each. It must be one element vs all other elements.

Now consider the *two* highest elements, having values M and M-d for some d. If we choose neither of them to be the singleton, they're both in the large-group side, which means that group has GCD at most d (since if g|M  and g|M-d then g|d); and the contribution of the singleton will be no more than M-d-1. So the overall score would be at most M-1 - that is, less than the score we get when choosing the highest value. **It is therefore the case that either the highest or the second-highest (distinct) value in the input must be in a set of its own.**

You must therefore need to do the following:

- Handle the trivial case of only one distinct value.
- Otherwise, obtain the 2 highest elements;.
- Compute the GCD g_0 of all the n-2 lowest elements.
- Compute the GCD's g_with_highest = GCD(g_0, M) and g_with_second_highest = GCD(g_0, M-d).
- Choose the singleton by comparing M + g_with_second_highest with (M-d) + g_with_highest.

Comment: I had the same idea bit but then I found (10, 5, 7). :(

Comment: Why only the 2 highest values? Why not checking for 3 or 4 highest values??

Comment: @sdrtgghytui: Because only the highest or the second-highest divisor can be the singleton. I've shown that, otherwise, the solution is sub-optimal.