# Counting number of "BAD" values

Tags: algorithm

I was solving a problem and came across this one.

Suppose we have some clay balls. Each ball has a certain value; the value of each ball may be any positive integer. Initially, for each value between X and X+Y−1 (inclusive), we has an infinite supply of balls with this values.

The balls have a special property: any two of them can be mixed to create a new ball. If the original balls had values a and b (possibly a=b), the new ball has value a+b. The balls created this way may be used to mix other balls as well. We are free to mix balls in any way we choose any number of times.

Let's call a value v (v>0) BAD if there is no way to obtain a ball with value v; otherwise, value v is GOOD. We want to make balls with all GOOD values and we would like to know the number of BAD values.

Note : There is an infinite number of GOOD values of balls, but it can be proven that the number of BAD values is always finite for Y≥2.

For a given X and Y devise a procedure to find the number of BAD values.

E.g.

```
X = 1 ; Y = 2
```

We are given `[1, 1 + 2 - 1] == [1, 2] == {1, 2}` balls. Answer **0** ; As it is possible to obtain balls with all possible values as per X and Y.

```
X = 3 ; Y = 3
```

We are given `[3, 3 + 3 - 1] == [3, 5] == {3, 4, 5}` balls.
Answer **2** ; As balls with values `1` and `2` cannot be made.

I thought that the values which are less than X cannot be made but it seems to be wrong, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Imagine, `X = 11, Y = 2` so you are given balls of `11` and `12`: you can't create `13`, `14`, ...`21`, `25` etc.

Comment: I don't think that the number of bad values is finite. If you have two even-numbered balls, say 2 and 4, how do you get an odd-numbered one ?

Comment: @ChatterOne: that's impossible: you are given a *range*, e.g. if `X = 2, Y = 3` it means you have `[2, 2 + 3 - 1]` - `{2, 3, 4}` balls

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh, I misread that you just had two values instead of a range. Ok, then.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Now I understood it, but how will  we be able to count these values?

Comment: @Steve: When solving such kind of problems, start from *playing* with numbers, let me not provide you the complete solution, but the idea with `1st` case (`Y = 2`) explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving such problems, start from **playing with numbers**. Suppose we are given `2` balls (`Y = 2`), let them be `11` and `12` (`X = 11`). We can create

- From `1` ball:   `11`, `12`
- From `2` balls:  `22`, `23`, `24`
- From `3` balls:  `33`, `34`, `35`, `36`
- From `4` balls:  `44`, `45`, `46`, `47`, `48`

....

We have *holes* (bad numbers) however: `1..10` of size `10` then `13..21` of size `9` then `25..32` of size `8`. Can you see the pattern? The sum of holes (number of bad numbers) is

```
10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 == 55
```

Now we can solve the problem if `Y = 2`: it's sum of *arthimetic progression*

```
X - 1 + X - 2 + ... + 2 + 1 == (X - 1) * (X - 2) / 2
```

Keep on doing on `Y = 3`, e.g. we are given `3` balls (`Y = 3`) `11, 12, 13` (`X = 11`). We can create:

- From `1` ball: `11`, `12`, `13`
- From `2` balls: `22`, `23`, `24`, `25`, `26`
- From `3` balls: `33`, `34`, `35`, `36`, `37`, `38`, `39`
- From `4` balls: `44`, `45`, `46`, `47`, `48`, `49`, `50`, `51`, `52`

Let's count holes: `1..10` then  `14..21` then `26..33` followed by `40..43`:

```
10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 == 30
```

Can you see the pattern? Can you solve for `Y = 3`? Please, note the difference:

```
 X = 11; Y = 2   ->   10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + ... + 1
 X = 11; Y = 3   ->   10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2
```

Can you write the formula for `Y = 3` now? For `Y = 4`, `Y = 5`?

```
 X = 11; Y = 4   ->   10 + 7 + 4 + 1
 x = 11; Y = 5   ->   10 + 6 + 2
```

For arbitrary `Y`?

```
 X = 11; Y       ->   10 + (10 - 1 * (Y - 1)) + (10 - 2 * (Y - 1)) + ...
```

For arbitrary `X` and `Y` (we have to sum all *positive* terms)?

```
 X; Y            ->   (X - 1) + (X - 1 - 1 * (Y - 1)) + (X - 1 - 2 * (Y - 1)) + ...
```

**Code:** Let it be **C#**:

```
private static int MySum(int X, int Y) {
  int d = Y - 1;                  // difference
  int n = (X - 1) / (Y - 1) + 1;  // number of items to sum

  int A1 = X - 1;                 // 1st item
  int An = X - 1 - (n - 1) * d;   // last item

  return (A1 + An) * n / 2;       // sum of arithmetic progression
}
```

**Some tests (or demo):**

```
(int, int)[] tests = new (int, int)[] {
   (X : 11, Y : 2),
   (X : 11, Y : 3),
   (X : 11, Y : 4),
   (X : 11, Y : 5),
   (X :  1, Y : 2),
   (X :  3, Y : 3),
};

string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"X = {test.Item1,2}, Y = {test.Item2} => {MySum(test.Item1, test.Item2),2}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
X = 11, Y = 2 => 55
X = 11, Y = 3 => 30
X = 11, Y = 4 => 22
X = 11, Y = 5 => 18
X =  1, Y = 2 =>  0 // test from the question
X =  3, Y = 3 =>  2 // test from the question
```

Comment: This is so elegant! Thanks a ton for the explanation.

Comment: Can you please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503879/maximize-the-sum-of-gcds-greatest-common-divisors-of-a-bipartition
I tried the implementation in the answer but fails for some cases.

Comment: @Steve: maximizing sum, of `gcd` seems to be a quite different problem; here we have an arthimetic progression to sum (a1 = `X - 1`, difference = `Y - 1` etc.)

Comment: I agree its a totally different problem, just wanted some insight into it

Comment: Just one more doubt as to how will we find 'N' i.e. the number of terms to use the sum of A.P formula? Sn =  [n*(2*a + (n-1)*d)] / 2

Comment: @Steve: Well, when we have the progression, all details seem to be pretty easy. OK, I've added some code (C#) with tests.

Comment: This code works! Just for one test-case it does not pass, as the input of X and Y is of the order of 10^18 and we need to compute it modulo 1000000007.
So can you please hep me incorporate this into each intermediate step because if we take it at the end it gives wrong answer.

Comment: @Steve: change `int` to `BigInt` or `long` in order to support range up to `1e18`

Comment: I did use long int. But they want the answer modulo 1e9 + 7.
So I'm going wrong in taking modulo at intermediate steps

Comment: @Steve: to compute modulo in case of c# put `%` operator. `return (...) % 1000000007;`

Comment: That is exactly what I did! Yet it fails for one case. I did some reading online and it says for large expressions we have to take %1000000007 at intermediate steps then it gives correct answer. (Distributive property of mod operator.)
I took modulo at steps in between but it gave wrong answer

Comment: @Steve: modulo arithmetics is not that easy. Probably, a better way out is to compute result via `BigInteger` which can be arbitrary long and then compute remainder

Comment: BigInt is the answer! Got accepted at last. Thanks a lot for the help.